# Any easy way to delete a user (having many to many relation with role) in acegi, grails?

Tags: grails, many-to-many, spring-security

In default acegi setting, person and authority have many to many relations.  Thus, in addtion to people and authorities, there is a table authotiries-people.

To delete a person (a user) I have to delete the related record in authotiries-people first....then come back to delete the record...

the problem is: other people are still using this authority (ROLE)

could some one enlighten me how to delete the user without deleting the authority?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this...

```
Authority.findAll().each { 
    it.removeFromPeople(person) 
}
person.delete()
```

The above removes the relationship between the person and authority first, then deletes the person. The authority itself is never deleted.